# Where query for get equals items from innerlist objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have following **Nodes** which is a collection

[image]

then once I expand expand **InnerList** it has following items

[image]

then once I expand one of this (**[0]**), it has following properties

[image]

then once I expand **Tag** it has a property call **Type** and this has string value.

[image]

so I just tried to write a query to select items by above  **Type** value
like following

```
var selectedValues = diagram.Nodes.Where(x => x.Tag).Where(A => A.Type.Equals("SomeValue"));
```

but this query can't even compile and getting theses errors

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'bool'. An explicit
> conversion exists
>
> Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because
> some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible
> to the delegate return type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Where` expects you to return a `bool` from your lambda. I'm not sure what you want to select but you need to adjust the first `Where` into a `Select` or combine it with your 2nd `Where`. Do you want something like this?

```
var selectedValues = diagram.Nodes.Where(x => 
    ((YourTagType)x.Tag).Type.Equals("SomeValue"));
```

Comment: Just add a null check on the Tag :))

Comment: getting this error with your approach `'object' does not contain a definition for 'Type' and no extension method 'Type' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found`

Comment: @kez you'll have to cast it.